# PDA for Context Free Grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, pushdown-automaton

```
G = ({S, X, Y}, {a, b}, P, S)

P = { 
S -> aXY | XbY
X -> bX | aS | e
Y -> a | e 
}
```

What is the language generated by this grammar? and which automaton accepts by empty stack, this language?

Comment: It seems to be Erlang for me.

Comment: The general method for converting between CFG and PDA can be found on cs.stackexchange.com or wikipedia: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/convert-cfg-to-pda.